# How to find number of characters in different screens in UWP WebView

Tags: string, uwp, character

I have a WebView to display characters in uwp. There I need to find how many characters are displayed in different screens for different font sizes. Is it possible to find a charater width for a given screen size and font size. Please explain how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find how many characters are displayed in different screens
>   for different font sizes.

There is no api can calculate how many characters are displayed in different screen size for different font sizes. Even if you set the same font size for each character, the width of them is still different, so you can't directly calculate the number of characters.